# How to pass an array of strings to a function in this program?

Tags: c, arrays, c-strings

I am a complete beginner with C and we have an assignment in class to take a given list of strings, put them in an array of strings, and pass that to a user-defined sort function that prints them in alphabetical order. Whenever I run my code, it does not give any compiler errors, but it also crashes immediately at runtime. Debugging gives me a segmentation fault, but it does not give me a specific line that caused it. I am running my code through the gcc compiler included in Dev C++.
Here is my code. Any help would be appreciated. I think my problem is trying to pass an array of strings to the function, but I haven't been able to find any answers on the subject that I could understand.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void sort(char *[]);

int main()
{
    char *states[4] = {0};
    states[0] = "Florida";
    states[1] = "Oregon";
    states[2] = "California";
    states[3] = "Georgia";

    sort(states);

    return 0;
}

void sort(char *ptr[])
{
    int i, j;
    char temp[20];
    for ( i = 1; i <= 4; i++ )
    {
        for ( j = 1; j <= 4; j++ )
            {
                if (strcmp(ptr[j-1], ptr[j]) > 0)
                {
                    strcpy(temp, ptr[j-1]);
                    strcpy(ptr[j-1], ptr[j]);
                    strcpy(ptr[j], temp);
                }
            }
    }

    int x;
    for ( x = 0; x < 4; x++ )
    {
        printf("%s", ptr[x]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: You are sorting pointers, not strings. See also [qsort](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/qsort.html)

Comment: whit this `j <= 4` then this `ptr[j]` is a problem.

Comment: You cannot call `strcpy` on `ptr[...]` because it points to a read-only memory segment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issues I see:

1. You are using the wrong indices in the `for` loops.

   Instead of:

   ```
   for ( i = 1; i <= 4; i++ )
   {
       for ( j = 1; j <= 4; j++ )
   ```

use:

```
    for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++ )   // Keep the values in the range 0 - 3.
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < 4; j++ )
```

1. You are modifying read-only memory.

   When you use:

   ```
   states[0] = "Florida";
   ```

   `states[0]` has the value of a read-only address that contains the string `"Florida"`. If you modify the values at that address, which you are doing in `sort`, you are entering undefined behavior territory.

You can fix the problem by switching pointers instead of copying the values.

```
    // Use char* for temp instead of an array
    char* temp;
    if (strcmp(ptr[j-1], ptr[j]) > 0)
    {
        temp = ptr[j-1];
        ptr[j-1] = ptr[j];
        ptr[j] = temp;
    }
```

**Addendum, in response to comment by OP**

The following version of `sort` works for me:

```
void sort(char *ptr[])
{
   int i, j;
   char* temp;
   for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
   {
      // NOTE:
      // This is different from your version.
      // This might fix your problem.
      for ( j = i+1; j < 4; j++ )
      {
         if (strcmp(ptr[j-1], ptr[j]) > 0)
         {
            temp = ptr[j-1];
            ptr[j-1] = ptr[j];
            ptr[j] = temp;
         }
      }
   }

   for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
   {
      printf("%s", ptr[i]);
      printf("\n");
   }
}
```

Comment: Ohhhh ok that makes a lot of sense. If you don't mind me asking another question, with these fixes, I get an output, but no matter how I set my array of strings, one of them is inevitably turned into this long string of completely random characters that is the same regardless of what the value in the array is.

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't know why my university decided that it would be a good idea to make the first intro to programming class in C, but they did. Also, I don't really know why changing the looping parameter like that would make a difference, but it does, so thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of crash is `j <= 4`. The other problem is that you want to swap pointers to string and not the chars.

```
void sort(char *ptr[])
{
    int i, j;
    char *temp;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) // sticking to array boundary convention
    {
        for ( j = 1; j < 4; j++ )
        {
            if (strcmp(ptr[j-1], ptr[j]) > 0)
            {
                // swap pointers 
                tmp = ptr[j];
                ptr[j] = ptr[j-1]; 
                ptr[j-1] = ptr[j];
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        printf("%s\n", ptr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C's Standard Library already comes with a function to sort arbitrary arrays of data. It is called [qsort](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/qsort.html).

`qsort` can sort arrays based on any criterion you supply using its fourth argument, the comparison function. In this case, we have a natural comparison function which we would like to shoehorn into using with what `qsort` expects.

So, `mycmpstr` below casts the incoming pointers appropriately, and returns the result of comparing strings using `strcmp`. We know that `qsort` will be calling our comparison function with constant pointers to constant char pointers, and we 'cast' appropriately.

Keep in mind that you are sorting pointers to character arrays. That means, you do not need to move the strings themselves, just the pointers. You use [strcmp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcmp.html) to decide which pointer should come before which based on the ordering of the strings to which they point.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int mycmpstr(const void *p, const void *q) {
    const char *const *x = p;
    const char *const *y = q;
    return strcmp(*x, *y);
}

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    const char *states[] = {
        "Florida", "Oregon", "California", "Georgia"
    };

    qsort(
        states,
        4,
        sizeof(char *),
        mycmpstr
    );

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i += 1) {
        puts(states[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ clang -Wall -O1 sortex.c -o sortex
$ ./sortex
California
Florida
Georgia
Oregon
```